# Extracting ZTE F670L router's config.bin file

Tags: binary-analysis, linux, decryption, encryption

I want to enable telnet in my router (**ZTE F670L V9.0.11P1N20D**), So, I backup my router and i have a file `config.bin`, Size 23.5KB. I fired up kali and when i issue this command:

```
$ file config.bin
config.bin: OpenPGP Public Key
```

I got this above output, I tried to extract this via binwalk, but no success.

Even though, Telnet is enabled on my router by default but the port is filtered:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp  open     ftp
23/tcp  filtered telnet
53/tcp  open     domain
80/tcp  open     http
139/tcp open     netbios-ssn
443/tcp open     https
```

I tried resetting the router but still Port is filtered.
So, I hope there's a solution to extract that `config.bin`.

Comment: i have problems getting firmware on ZTE f670L. Would you kindly share your latest firmware file?

Comment: fw pls? can i have ur latest fw ?